# Unresolved dependencies in the protocol buffer java source code

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use Protocol buffers in my project(web-app) based in Java. I downloaded zip   `Protocol Buffers 2.4.0a full source(C++,Java,Python)` & `Protocol Buffers 2.4.0 compiler-Windows binary`.

I was able to build the .proto file and generate the required java classes for my project, using the protoc compiler. Then I included the java folder(protobuf-2.4.0a\java\src\main\java......)  contained in the PB's downloaded zipped source code to my project's `src` directory. However as I can see in my IDE, some of its dependencies of those files are not yet resolved. and I was not able to deserialize the messages when i tried out, (I guess I was able to serialize, however).

Could you help me by letting me know what needs to be fixed ? Shouldnt I be instead putting a jar in my classpath rather than including the PB source code to my src folder?

*(I didnt used maven anywhere to download anything. I do not know how to use maven)*

Comment: "Some of its dependencies of those files" - could you give more details?

Comment: in the `Descriptors.java` file in the src code, there is an import statement: `com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos.*;` This package does not exist at all

Comment: Okay, I wondered whether that might be it... but I'm surprised you've managed to serialize anything then.

Comment: may be it didnt serialized but I got no errors while serializing(except when deserializing)  and I was able to get the length of serialized bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate and build the Java code corresponding to the protobuf descriptors.

There are instructions for this near the bottom of the [README.txt file in the java directory](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/README.txt).

Comment: Thanks Jon.. I could nt understand this syntax..if you could clarify a bit please.....   2) Invoke protoc to build DescriptorProtos.java:

     $ protoc --java_out=src/main/java -I../src \
         ../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto

Comment: @aklin: The "$" represents the unix command prompt, and "\" is just a way of saying "continues on the next line". Just run `protoc --java_out=src/main/java -I../src ../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto`

Comment: Thanks Jon! your solution worked! but is it the proper way to include the src files of PB in my own code, rather cant I have a jar included in my classpath.?

Comment: @aklin: You don't have to - once the Java sources have been generated, you can build all of the PB code into your own jar file. It's just it doesn't *come* as a jar file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jon!!Great help!

Comment: Google protocol buffer is such a mess to install, getting all sorts of dependencies errors and it has really poor documentation at google site, at least they could add easy step by step installation steps... i have wasted more than six hours trying to add jar files, add source files, and getting errors, and unable to generate DesriptorProtos :/